# How to add object properties from ng-checked items to my ng-model object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have four input fields which I'm using to add properties to a single object using ng-model= model.propertyName. I have a series of check boxes that I'm creating with ng-repeat that I could not figure out how to add unique propertyNames for each ng-model as they were created with the ng-repeat. As a work-around(or maybe this is correct, I'm not sure) I was able to write a function to add the checked items to an array. I was then trying to use a for-loop to iterate over the array and add each selected propertyName(string) to the ng-model object as a new property using a ng-click to call the function.

As-is when I click the "Add Technician" button I get the following error output:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined
>       at Scope.$scope.addTechnician (..../scripts/controllers.js:

This occurs because $scope is undefined inside the conditional of my for loop in the addTechnician function. I can't understand why because when I pass $scope to the addTechnician function it recognizes the newTech inside the for loop. When I don't pass $scope to the addTechnician function it says newTech is undefined with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'cert1' of undefined
>   at Scope.$scope.addTechnician(.../scripts/controllers)

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with the way ng-repeat creates a new scope, which prototypically inherits from the parent scope. But again, I'm not sure.

Here is my controller

```
use strict';
angular.module('Carrepair2.controllers', [])

.controller('SetupCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.certifications = [
    {'name':'Engine Repair'},
    {'name':'A/T & Transaxle'},
    {'name':'Manual Drive Train & Axles'},
    {'name':'Suspension & Steering'},
    {'name':'Brakes'},
    {'name':'Electrical & Electronic Systems'},
    {'name':'Heating & Air Conditioning'},
    {'name':'Engine Performance'},
    {'name':'Light Vehicle Diesel Engines'}
  ];

  // selected certifications
  $scope.selection = [];

  $scope.toggleCert = function(name) {
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(name);

    //is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    //is newly selected
    else{
      $scope.selection.push(name);
    }
  };

  $scope.addTechnician = function($scope) {
    for(var i=0; i < $scope.selection.length - 1; i++){
      $scope.newTech['cert' + (i + 1).toString()] = $scope.selection[i].name;
    }
  };

})
```

Here is my template

```
<form class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="first-name" ng-model="newTech.firstName" required>
        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input type="text" name="last-name" ng-model="newTech.lastName" required>
        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="newTech.email" required>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrapper">
        <input type="tel" name="phone" ng-model="newTech.phone" required>
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    </div>
    <h5>Check all held ASE certifications</h5>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat="certification in certifications">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{certification.name}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(certification.name) > -1" ng-click="toggleCert(certification)">
        </label>
        {{certification.name}}
    </li>
    </ul>
    <button class="button button-block" ng-click="addTechnician()">Add Technician</button>
</form>
```

Ideally after the "Add Technician" button is clicked I want to end up with an object, my newTech ng-model object, that has the input field data and the properties from the checked items. Here is a jsFiddle with simplified code replicating the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/aq93z/7/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had to format my loop using `angular.forEach(values, function(value, index){`here is the jsFiddle with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/aq93z/9/. If you look at the $scope.newTech object created in the console the checkbox selections are added as properties of the newTech ng-model object.